# Goldbach Conjecture related modular arithmetic problem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem, goldbachs-conjecture

The modular arithmetic problem is related to the construction of a certain integer $\delta$ for some given $n$ such that $n \pm \delta$ are both positive primes. The problem is:

We will say $X \equiv (a_1, \ldots ,a_m) \mod (p_1,\ldots,p_m)$ if $X \equiv a_i \mod p_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,m$.

Suppose $X \equiv (a_1, \ldots ,a_m) \mod (p_1,\ldots,p_m)$ for primes $p_i$. Chinese Remainder Theorem tells us that there is a unique element $X$ that satisfies these congruences that lie between $0$ and $\prod p_i$. Let $n$ be a positive integer less than $\prod p_i$. How can we tell based on $X \equiv (a_1,\ldots,a_m)$ whether or not $X<n$?

Any ideas are welcome. Thank you.

Comment: $(1)$ I do not see the analogy to Golbbach $(2)$ I doubt that we can determine whether $X<n$ without just calculating the solution.

Comment: @Peter (1) $$p+q=2n\implies p+q=n+n\implies q-n=n-p$$

Comment: Without some computation on the values using $p_i$ it doesn't seem likely. if $p_i=3k+2\land a_i=3j+1$ and $X\equiv 2\bmod 3$ then $k=3l+2$ and we can rule out $n$ as possible if $p_i$ is larger than half.